# Keep certain divs together when wrapping

Tags: css

I have a container with multiple sibling `div` elements. These elements are interrupted by other `div` elements that are technically siblings yet are not like the others.  They're not delimiters but that is a decent analogy. I want to keep the div-clusters between delimiters together on the line when a wrap happens. In the snippet below, there are five such clusters: ABC,  DEFGH, IJKLM, and NO.

Is it possible to add an identifying class to each `div` in a cluster that belongs together, and then apply css to that class that would keep them together?  I am hoping to avoid changing the structure.

```css
#foo div{
           text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        
          #foo p[contenteditable="true"] {
                /* font-size: 22px;*/
                height: 22px;
                width: 22px;
                color: black;
                font-weight: bold;
                /* border: 1px dotted black;*/
                background-color: cyan;
            }

            #foo p.const {
                background-color: inherit;
                border: none;
                height: 22px;
                width: 22px;
            }
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="0"></p>
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="1"></p>
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="2"></p>
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="3"></p>
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="4"></p>
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="5"></p>
    <p>F</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="6"></p>
    <p>G</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="7"></p>
    <p>H</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">"</p>
    <p>"</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="8"></p>
    <p>I</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="9"></p>
    <p>J</p>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
    <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="10"></p>
    <p>K</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="11"></p>
    <p>L</p>
  </div class="group">
  <div>
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="12"></p>
    <p>M</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="const">"</p>
    <p>"</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="13"></p>
    <p>N</p>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <p contenteditable="true" tabindex="14"></p>
    <p>O</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow:auto` on the container is what I've seen most recommended, but that keeps all of the chunks together on one line with a horizontal scrollbar, when what I want to do is to keep the divs of the individual chunks together and allow breaks at the "delimiter".

Comment: I think what you want is `#foo div.group { display: inline-block; }` so that only `<div>`s with that class are inlined.

Comment: @Noam. Thanks for the suggestion. As you were typing I was just modifying the structure to enclose the clusters in a container div and it seems to be working as desired. Since I prefer to to modify the structure, I will give your suggestion a try at home.